# javascript namespace issue (I think)

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I've been making a jQuery plugin for password boxes. It adds a generate password button and strength indicator to inputs that are passed to it via a jQuery selector.

I'm having an issue with the code on lines 154 & 155 of jquery.password.js `inputPassword.position().top`. It's not returning the correct position of the input box, so the error message isn't appearing in the correct place.

I think this is probably an issue with `inputPassword` not being in the correct namespace, or something like that, but I don't fully understand how these things work in javascript... this is my first jQuery plugin.

Thanks

**** link removed *****

It wasn't namespaces, it was because the object was hidden. So fixed with:

    `if ( inputPassword.is(":visible") ) {
        positionObject = inputPassword;
    } else {
        positionObject = inputPlain;
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position()` returns the offset relative to the parent, however, as the element you're trying to position is positioned absolutely, you might find it works if you use [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) instead.

Edit: `inputPassword` is hidden whilst you're retrieving the `offset()`/ `position()`. From the docs: **Note: jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden elements.**

Comment: Your link to offset is not the correct one. It can be found here. http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: nope, i tried that but it still gets positioned relative the top left of the screen